# How to slice Json objects?

Tags: php, arrays, json

There is PHP object that including in it three arrays and Json receiving them.
So what I need is to slice this Object and return the three arrays separately.

## Php code:

```
  $row = array(array($directionsStart),array($directionsEnd),$directionsWaypointArray);
  echo json_encode($row);
```

PHP Object:

```
[["Belo Horizonte, Minas Gerais"],["Maric\u00e1, Rio de Janeiro"],["Monte Mor, S\u00e3o Paulo","Maric\u00e1, Rio de Janeiro","Maric\u00e1, Rio de Janeiro","Belo Horizonte, Minas Gerais"]]
```

## Json

```
success: function(msg) {
     var dd = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(msg));
     console.log('First:'+dd+' Second: '+dd+' Third: '+dd);
}
```

Output of `dd` should be like that:

```
First: ["Belo Horizonte, Minas Gerais"]
Second: ["Maricá, Rio de Janeiro"]
Third: ["Monte Mor, São Paulo","Maricá, Rio de Janeiro","Maricá, Rio de Janeiro","Belo Horizonte, Minas Gerais"]
```

Comment: $directionsStart and the other two variables - are those JSON strings? or PHP arrays?

Comment: they are php array @Dan

Comment: after stringify and parse, when you console.log(dd) - what is the output?

Comment: going to update the post with more info

Comment: done the updates .. as you see there is 3 groups of arrays and i need to separate them when call them back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
success: function(msg) {
     var dd = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(msg));
     console.log('First:'+dd[0]+' Second: '+dd[1]+' Third: '+dd[2]);
}
```

Comment: can you use without JSON.parse and JSON stringify? couse you are returning JSON which is string itself

Comment: if there is any other way, when i get call back can separate arrays sure will be a welcome solution.

Comment: cant get what you said, can you provide output what you get when you console.log(dd[0]) ? also did you checked JSON.parse(msg) without JSON.stringify?

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(msg) {
     var [dd1, dd2, dd3] = JSON.parse(msg);
     console.log('First:'+dd1+' Second: '+dd2+' Third: '+dd3);
}
```

Comment: its just considered `dd1` and nothing more!

Comment: please post the result you were getting from the whole dd var